How to clear TextField upon first focus in Jetpack Compose
I am wondering if anyone has tried to modify the value of text in a TextField Component upon clicking into it the first time. I.e. There is example text, you click on it and the text disappears, with cursor, keyboard and focus available. Im finding that when I the textfield is focused with keyboard up, there cannnot be a change to the value of the field. I also have not found a way to intercept focus first in order to clear the textfield before hand. If i release focus in the focus listener then change the value I can clear it, but then the user is not actually typing in the box anymore. Any idea how I can attach a clear function to the onfocus listener?

Hope you are expecting placeholder , try this
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
    },
    label = {
        Text("Label")
    },
    placeholder = {
        Text("Placeholder")  // this text will hide when keyboard on focus
    }
)


There is also a placeholder, but this textfield has a value already of "Current Location" and I need to clear that value once user clicks on it. The problem is when it gains focus, any recomposition is stopped because the user is engaged in typing
